# Solving for $f(2004)$ in a given functional equation

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

Given that $$f(1)=2005$$ and $$f(1)+f(2)+...f(n) = n^{2}f(n)$$
for all $n>1$. Determine the value of $f(2004)$.

My progress:

I first substituted $n-1$ into the equation to get $f(1)+f(2)+...+f(n-1) = (n-1)^{2}f(n-1)$ and then I subtracted it from the first equation to get $$f(n) = n^{2}f(n)-(n-1)^{2}f(n-1)$$.
I got a little stuck so I checked the answers for a hint and it said that: $$f(n) = \frac{(n-1)^{2}}{n^{2}-1}f(n-1)$$.
How is this so? I don't understand the last part.

Comment: It's just algebraic manipulation from the result you came up with. $$f(n)-n^2f(n)=(1-n^2)f(n)=-(n-1)^2f(n-1)$$

Comment: Thanks. I see what you did.

Answer (score 2):

Then... from this equation you can easily get that:

$f(n) = (2 / (n(n+1))).f(1)$

How? Just express f(n) by f(n-1), then f(n-1) by f(n-2) and so on until you reach the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You have $$\begin{align}f(1)+f(2)+...+f(n-1)+f(n) &= n^{2}f(n)\end{align}$$

send that $f(n)$ to right hand side and get
$$\begin{align}f(1)+f(2)+...+f(n-1) &= n^{2}f(n)-f(n)\\~\\&=(n^2-1)f(n)\end{align}$$

Next observe that left hand side becomes $(n-1)^2f(n-1)$

Comment: Where did the $(n-1)^{2}$ from the LHS come from?

Comment: @Aspiring: From the functional equation for case $n-1$.

Comment: does that make sense @AspiringMathlete

Comment: Yes but is this after we subtracted or before we subtracted?

Comment: $$f(1) + f(2) + \cdots + f(n-1) = (n-1)^2f(n-1)$$that comes from the given functional equation for case $n-1$ as mentioned by Regret earlier

Answer (score 1):

Because $n^2-1 = (n-1)(n+1)$, you can get
\begin{align}
f(n) = \frac{n-1}{n+1}f(n-1)
\end{align}
The remaining is simple.

Comment: $(n-1)^2=(n-1)(n-1)$.

Comment: Sorry, I've mistyped. I meant n^2 - 1 = (n-1)(n+1).

Answer (score 1):

$f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+...+f(n)=n^2f(n)$

and similarly

$f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+...+f(n-1)=(n-1)^2f(n-1)$

Subtracting the second from the first we get
$$
f(n)=n^2f(n)-(n-1)^2f(n-1)     
$$i.e 
$$
f(n)=n^2f(n)-(n-1)^2f(n-1)     
$$ or
$$
0=(n^2-1)f(n)-(n-1)^2f(n-1)     
$$ i.e
$$
f(n)=\frac{(n-1)^2f(n-1))}{(n^2-1)}
$$
$$
f(n)=\frac{n-1}{n+1}f(n-1)
$$
Replacing $n$ by $n-1$ and so on we get the equation
$$
f(n)=\frac{n-1}{n+1}\frac{n-2}{n}\frac{n-3}{n-1}\dots\frac{3}{5}\frac{2}{4}\frac{1}{3}f(1)
$$ Cancelling out the common terms we get
$$
f(n)=\frac{2*f(1)}{(n+1)(n)}
$$ 
$$
\therefore f(2004)=\frac{2*2005}{2005*2004}=\frac{1}{1002}
$$